# Dropwizard - Postgresql - Hibernate mapping timestamp with time zone on LocalDateTime

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, dropwizard

I have a problem with mapping postgresql type 'timestamp with time zone' on java.time.LocalDateTime. I'm using: postgresql, dropwizard with hibernate.

Table:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "auth"."roles_seq_id";

CREATE TABLE "auth"."roles" (
  id        BIGINT                  NOT NULL    DEFAULT nextval('auth.roles_seq_id'),
  name      VARCHAR(50)             NOT NULL,
  createdat TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE "auth"."roles" ADD CONSTRAINT "roles_id_pk" PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Core:

```
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(schema = "auth", name = "roles")
public class Role implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "roles_id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "roles_id_generator", sequenceName = "roles_seq_id")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "createdat")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

}
```

Error:

> ERROR [2017-07-21 08:13:43,165]
>   io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a
>   request: b09a66b06dd214bd ... ! Causing:
>   org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize

POM.XML:

```
<dropwizard.version>1.0.6</dropwizard.version>
<postgresql.version>9.4.1212</postgresql.version>

 <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
 </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

When I delete `createdAt` or I use `private Date createdAt` (but I want to use LocalDateTime), everything is ok.

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using?

Comment: Added to the post

Comment: Just after a quick look, it appears that Dropwizard is using Hibernate v5.1.0, might you need the `hibernate-java8` dependency?

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
I used this code and working. Thanks.

Comment: Oh good, I formalised that as an answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `dropwizard-hibernate:1.0.6` bundles Hibernate 5.1. According to [the manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-datetime-java8) an extra dependency is required to support the `java.time` types:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Additionally, as of Hibernate 5.2, this extra dependency is not required, it seems the functionality was folded into the main dependency.